# Maven release:prepare No such provider: 'svn+ssh'

Tags: eclipse, maven, svn, maven-release-plugin

I'm attempting to experiment with release management using maven.  In my pom I have my scm connection defined.

```
<scm>
    <connection>scm:svn+ssh://xxxxxxx/usr/local/svn/myproject/trunk</connection>
    <developerConnection>scm:svn+ssh://xxxxxxx/usr/local/svn/myproject/trunk</developerConnection>
    <url>http://xxxxxxx/usr/local/svn/myproject/trunk</url>
</scm>
```

When I attempt to run the goal release:prepare I get the following error:

Failed to execute goal org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-release-plugin:2.0:prepare (default-cli) on project myproject: The provider given in the SCM URL could not be found: No such provider: 'svn+ssh'. -> [Help 1]

I can successfully navigate to the location using tortoisesvn.  I'm using Eclipse Luna with Maven 3.0.5

Answer (score 0):

After much experimentation I figured it out.  It's supposed to be scm:svn:svn+ssh://....